# How to implement boost::serialize for tbb::concurrent_vector

Tags: c++, boost, tbb, boost-serialization, concurrent-vector

I am using tbb::concurrent_vector in place of std::vector in some places but am also using boost serialization in order to serialise the containers, and concurrent_vector does not come with one provided (obviously).

Any idea how to implement this easily and correctly?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use non-intrusive serialization. The simplest I can think of:

```
template <typename Ar, typename... Ts>
void serialize(Ar& ar, tbb::concurrent_vector<Ts...>& v, unsigned) {
    size_t n = v.size();

    ar & n;
    if constexpr (Ar::is_loading::value)
        v.resize(n);
    ar & make_array(&v.front(), n);
}
```

However this would be very wrong, as `concurrent_vector` is apparently [not a vector](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/onetbb/developer-guide-api-reference/2021-9/concurrent-vector.html#:%7E:text=because%20elements%20in%20a%20concurrent_vector%20might%20not%20be%20at%20consecutive%20addresses) at all:

> [because] *elements in a concurrent_vector might not be at consecutive addresses*

### Fix

We can take a hint from e.g. `boost/serialization/list.hpp` and reuse their collection loading/saving primitives. This has the benefit of also adding correct item versioning and NVP wrapping (e.g. needed for XML archives)

### Demo Time

**[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a253d6c0b3adcf73)**

```
#include <boost/serialization/collections_load_imp.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/collections_save_imp.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/library_version_type.hpp>
#include <tbb/concurrent_vector.h>

namespace boost::serialization {
    template <typename Ar, typename... Ts>
    inline void save(Ar& ar, tbb::concurrent_vector<Ts...> const& t, unsigned) {
        boost::serialization::stl::save_collection<Ar, tbb::concurrent_vector<Ts...>>(ar, t);
    }

    template <typename Ar, typename... Ts>
    inline void load(Ar& ar, tbb::concurrent_vector<Ts...>& t, unsigned) {
        item_version_type    item_version(0);
        collection_size_type count;
        ar >> BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(count);
        if (library_version_type{3} < ar.get_library_version())
            ar >> BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(item_version);
        stl::collection_load_impl(ar, t, count, item_version);
    }

    template <typename Ar, typename... Ts>
    inline void serialize(Ar& ar, tbb::concurrent_vector<Ts...>& t, unsigned version) {
        boost::serialization::split_free(ar, t, version);
    }

} // namespace boost::serialization

#include <boost/serialization/collection_traits.hpp>

BOOST_SERIALIZATION_COLLECTION_TRAITS(tbb::concurrent_vector)

#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <fmt/ranges.h>
int main() {
    std::stringstream ss;

    boost::archive::text_oarchive(ss) << tbb::concurrent_vector<int>{1, 2, 3};

    tbb::concurrent_vector<int> roundtrip;
    fmt::print("Archive: {}\n", ss.str());

    boost::archive::text_iarchive(ss) >> roundtrip;
    fmt::print("Deserialized: {}\n", roundtrip);
}
```

Printing

```
Archive: 22 serialization::archive 19 3 0 1 2 3

Deserialized: [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: ideally, the library should provide a method to access each contiguous segment and the array serialization could operate on each segment at time. This might create extra levels in XML archives if one is not careful though.